# JS: почему слово не попадает в условие, хотя идентичные слова в него попадают?

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, if, foreach

Написал код на js, который должен вставлять в английское слово тире между двумя подряд идущими, повторяющимися буквами:

else {

```
            let lettersArr = inputWord.split('');
            
            lettersArr.forEach(function(letter) {
                console.log(letter);
                let index = lettersArr.findIndex(i => i == letter);
                
                if(lettersArr[index] == result[1] && lettersArr[index + 1] == result[1]) {
                    
                    lettersArr[index] = lettersArr[index] + '—';
                   
                }
                
            });

            let withTransfer = lettersArr.join("");

            alert(withTransfer);
        }
```

Слово dubble, попадая в условие благополучно делится...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А слово bubble - почему-то нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод в console.log (console.log(letter);) в коде у двух слов одинаковый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, bubble просто не попадает в условие if (тем более, что внутри условия для этого слова уже ничего не "консольложится"). А почему так? Не могу понять (

Comment: что у вас в result[1] ?

Comment: @Konst result[1] результат применения регулярки к строке.. Проверил в случае bubble, result[0] содержит "bb", result[1] - "b".

Comment: @Konst регулярка отбирает слова, у которых есть две повторяющиеся буквы подряд.. let result = inputWord.match(/(.)\1/);

Comment: сложно понять, что у вас не так, пока не будет полного кода, который можно выполнить

Comment: не могу, к сожалению, запрещают нам..

Comment: puppet тоже проверку не проходит..

Comment: проверку не проходят слова, у которых первая буква такая же, как удвоенные согласные в середине